# How to hide MS Access query column with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have searched older posts, but couldnt find a solution. 
I got a query with many columns. I have created a basic search form, where I can input criteria for all the columns in that query, so I can perform the search. Problem is, I dont need to show all the columns. For example, there could be a checkmark for every column in the form, to hide/show it the query result. Could someone help me with the code, to achieve it? I need it in checkmark's AfterUpdate event. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: in the sql just dont select them?

Comment: Ok, sounds simple, but how to do it with checkmark in form?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own checkboxes and making your own events, you could simply create a "Show/Hide" button that when clicked will allow the user to select which columns they want to view.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub btnShowHide_Click()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUnhideColumns
End Sub
```

**What it Does:**

This will make it so that when the user clicks the `btnShowHide` button, it will show a menu where the user can check or uncheck the columns that they want to hide.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get run-time error - The command or action 'UnhideColumns' isnt available now.

Comment: @tomsre What kind of a form do you have that shows these columns?  I had just assume it was a splitform by the way you were speaking about it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, I have a simple form. In form i have a button witch runs the query. I want to adjust the query's columns "Show" atribute from the form. In other words, when I uncheck my checkbox in my form, it need to uncheck the "Show" checkbox, what you can find in query design view.

Comment: What do you mean? The database is used only by me.

Comment: @tomsre Okay, so would simply right clicking on one of the column headers and selecting "UnHide" work in your situation.  That will bring up a list of all of the columns and you just choose which ones you want to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I guess you dont actually understand what I need. I have a search form with text boxes where I enter search criteria. Just likethis one created in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTiA_4Me0cI/  ... I want checkboxes in the form next to every text box and if I unckeck the checkbox next to on of the text boxes, that column in query doesnt show up when I run it.